# Size and resolution of videos within the iOS app bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsbundle

What are the different video size and resolutions that can be added within the bundle of an iOS app to play for all iPhone and iPad models. Is there any limitations over size and resolutions of videos. What is the proper video/size to play well on all devices

Answer (score 1):

There are many downsides to including large amounts of content (a large total bundle size will force your users to install over WiFi, for example) but as to specific content size/format restrictions, there aren't any.

Just in case... If you're talking about "what is the proper video format/size to play well on all devices", that's a different question and not the one I am answering (effectively, "aggregate bundle content size").

Comment: Thanks. How about the proper video format/size to play well on all devices

Comment: That one to me is a matter of opinion because "play well" has many different definitions for different kinds of videos, but folks better versed in the content should answer. The one app I had a hand in with an embedded video went with a 720 version - 330MB. If the conditions surrounding that decision would have allowed, device-specific server streaming on-demand (or at least on-demand download) would have been a better choice.